# Inverse function of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following task:

Let $U,V$ be open sets in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:U\to V$ is surjective. Futhermore there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq k\cdot|x-y|$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $f$ is bijective and $f^{-1}$ holomorphic.

I have already shown that $f$ is bijective. And I also know the proof using $f^{\prime}(z)\neq 0$. But can I show that without using $f^{\prime}(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: note that taking the limit as $y \to x$ you get that $|f'(x)| \ge k>0$

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Now I could solve the task!